# How to format formRadio() Zend Framework

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-form

Hi I'm using formRadio() to display two options with radio buttons. Example

```
<li><?php echo $this->formRadio('johnsmith', '1', array(), array('1' => 'Yes', '0' => 'No'), ' '); ?></li>
```

Getting HTML output

```
<li>
   <label for="johnsmith-1">
     <input type="radio" name="johnsmith" id="johnsmith-1" value="1" checked="checked">
   Yes
   </label>
</li>
<li>
  <label for="johnsmith-0">
    <input type="radio" name="johnsmith" id="johnsmith-0" value="0">
   No
   </label>
</li>
```

but im looking HTML like

```
<li>
   <input type="radio" name="johnsmith" id="johnsmith-1" value="1" checked="checked">
   <label for="johnsmith-1">Yes</label>
<li>
<li>
  <input type="radio" name="johnsmith" id="johnsmith-0" value="0">
  <label for="johnsmith-0">No</label>
</li>
```

Can anybody help me please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to create your own `Element` and `Decorator` for this.

The view helper `formRadio()` will display a default rendering for the buttons.

Comment: Thanks, could you provide some example please ?

Answer (score 0):

For all questions regarding Zend Form markup I recommend to see first:

[Leveraging Zend_Form Decorators](http://www.slideshare.net/weierophinney/leveraging-zendform-decorators)

After watching this presentation, you will be able to create any markup for any element.